Python issue with importing from submodule including scripts that also import from submodule?
My Python project has the following file structure.
module/
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
│
└── sub_module/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── foo1.py
    └── foo2.py

My goal is to import a class Bar from foo1.py in main.py:
from sub_module.foo1 import Bar

It's important to know that foo1.py also imports from foo2.py, which currently works fine when I run python3 foo1.py.
from foo2 import some_function

Both init.py files are empty.
Here is the exception that I currently get, when attempting to run python3 main.py:
File "/.../module/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sub_module.foo1 import Bar
File "/.../module/sub_module/foo1.py", line 24, in <module>
    from foo2 import some_function

How can I get this working?
Thanks.

usually (sub)modules should use relative imports to other submodules - but it can make problem when you want to run directly submodule. OR it may need to use from sub_module.foo2 ... insfead of from foo2 ...

The problem is actually with from foo2 import some_function in foo1.py.
When running foo1.py the file is found. This is because the current working directory is sub_module and the path to the file is a relative.
When running main.py this file 'foo2.py' is not found. This is because the current working directory is module. For the relative path to find the file, you would need have from sub_module.foo2 import some_function.
This isn't a great way of importing modules within a package.
The best way is to use absolute locations. This means that whichever file runs the code, it can find the module.
Firstly, removing __init__.py in module. I don't believe this is needed.
# main.py
from sub_module.foo1 import Bar

# foo1.py
from sub_module.foo2 import some_function

If the above is still not working, you need to check your current working directory. This can be done by adding the following to your main.py. It's important that you include every directory from the working directory to the desired file.
import os
print(os.getcwd())

For more information on imports, the documentation is here:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Thanks, however in my case this doesn't seem to work.
When I use from module.sub_module.foo1 import Bar, I now get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module'.

Is module the root directory? Are there any other directories with __init__.py above module?

Yes, module is the root directory and there's no __init__.py in the directory above, except in sub-directories of the above parent directory, where I keep other work-in-progress Python projects.

I've had a bit of a play round and I think I found the problem. I've updated my answer to show the changes.

I would propose you the following solution to your problem, because your program has issues with the relative paths of your modules. To make them visible futher in the path-tree i'm using the __all__ module-variable, like the following :
#foo2.py

__all__ = ["some_function"]

def some_function():
     print("in foo2")

#foo1.py
from .foo2 import some_function

some_function()

__all__ = ["Bar"]

class Bar:
    pass

print("--end in foo1--")

# ..\sub_module\__init__.py
from .foo1 import *
from .foo2 import *

__all__ = (foo1.__all__ + foo2.__all__ )


# main.py
from sub_module import Bar # no need to call explicitly elements anymore

Then it works as expected : ..\module>python main.py 
in foo2
--end in foo1--

Thanks this works! Although your sample code was a bit confusing, since under #foo1.py and #foo2.py, your doing exactly the same. #foo2.py should have some_function() and #foo1.py the class Bar. You're an edit away from the check mark. ;)

Although this is a good solution to the problem, I wouldn't recommend this method as the best option. It requires a lot of extra code, which can be achieved by simply using absolute paths.

For sure, this is just my personal preference, because it gives me the feel that I would need to make a lot of absolute imports, which I'll need to change at some point

Thanks again, @baskettaz. I've awarded the check mark to the above answer, but yours is great as well.
